Express server is returning an HTML page when the registration form is expecting a JSON response
When attempting to register a user to the database I am hit with
Register.jsx:54 Registration error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON.
I am using express as the server-side with mongoDB and react as the front end. I assume it has to do with the pathing but I am at a loss on where the issue might be.
My App.jsx:
// IMPORTS HERE
import './App.css'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import WelcomeMessage from './components/WelcomeMessage'
import SortFilterMenu from './components/SortFilterMenu'
import Login from '../src/pages/Login';
import Register from '../src/pages/Register';
// import FetchAndDisplayFromQueue from './FetchAndDisplayFromQueue';


function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<><WelcomeMessage/><SortFilterMenu/></>} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        {/* More routes can be added here */}
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App

Register.jsx goes as follows:
import { useState } from 'react';

function Register() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');

  const handleRegister = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      console.error("Passwords don't match.");
      return;
    }

    const registerData = {
      username: username,
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };

    try {
      const response = await fetch('/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(registerData),
        credentials: 'include', // Needed for cookies
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("Registration successful");
        window.location.href = '/login';
      } else {
        const errorData = await response.json();
        throw new Error(errorData.error || 'Failed to register');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Registration error:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center min-vh-100">
      <div className="row border rounded-5 p-4 bg-white shadow box-area">
        <div className="col-md-6 rounded-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column left-box" style={{ background: '#00011a'}}>
        <div className="featured-image mb-3">
            <img src="/logo.png" className="img-fluid" alt="logo" style={{ width: '250px' }} />
          </div>
          <p className="text-white fs-2" style={{ fontFamily: "'Courier New', Courier, monospace", fontWeight: 600 }}>Welcome Back!</p>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6 right-box">
          <form onSubmit={handleRegister}>
          
            <div className="header-text mb-4">
              <h2>CinemaWorld</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="input-group mb-3" style={{ marginLeft: '15px' }}>
                <input 
                  name="username" 
                  type="text" 
                  className="form-control form-control-lg bg-light fs-6" 
                  placeholder="Username" 
                  required 
                  value={username} 
                  onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)} 
                />
              </div>
            <div className="input-group mb-3" style={{ marginLeft: '15px' }}>
                <input 
                  name="email" 
                  type="email" 
                  className="form-control form-control-lg bg-light fs-6" 
                  placeholder="Email address" 
                  required 
                  value={email} 
                  onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} 
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-group mb-3" style={{ marginLeft: '15px' }}>
                <input 
                  name="password" 
                  type="password" 
                  className="form-control form-control-lg bg-light fs-6" 
                  placeholder="Password" 
                  required 
                  value={password} 
                  onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} 
                />
              </div>
            <div className="input-group mb-3" style={{ marginLeft: '15px' }}>
              <input 
                name="confirmPassword" 
                type="password" 
                className="form-control form-control-lg bg-light fs-6" 
                placeholder="Confirm Password" 
                required 
                value={confirmPassword} 
                onChange={e => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)} 
              />
            </div>
            {/* Rest of your form content */}
            <div className="input-group mb-3" style={{ marginLeft: '15px' }}>
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-lg btn-primary w-100 fs-6">Register</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Register;


The route setup in my route.js:
router.post('/register', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;

    // Create a new User instance with the extracted fields
    const newUser = new User({ username, email, password });

   
    await newUser.save();

    // Redirect to login on successful registration
    res.redirect('/login');
  } catch (error) {
    // Check for a MongoDB duplicate key
    if (error.code === 11000) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Email or username already exists." });

    }
    
    // Log the full error for debugging purposes
    console.error('Registration error:', error);

    // Send a generic error response
    return res.status(400).json({error:"An error occurred during registration."});
  }
});

My server.js used to run the backend:
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
const app = express();

// Import routes
const userRoutes = require('./routes/route');
const apiRoutes = require('./routes/api');

app.use(helmet()); // Set security-related HTTP headers
app.use(rateLimit({ // Basic rate-limiting middleware
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  max: 100 // Limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { secure: false, httpOnly: true }
}));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(flash());

const authMiddleware = require('./middleware/authentication');
app.use(authMiddleware.initialize());
app.use(authMiddleware.session());

// Connect to MongoDB
const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to connect to MongoDB', err);
    process.exit(1); // Exit process with failure
  }
};

connectDB();

// Error handling middleware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  console.error(err);
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    res.status(statusCode).json({ error: err.message, stack: err.stack });
  } else {
    res.status(statusCode).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(error.status || 500).json({
    error: {
      message: error.message || 'An unknown error occurred.',
    },
  });
});

// Use routes
app.use('/', userRoutes);
app.use('/', apiRoutes);

// Start server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`)).on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Failed to start server:', err);
});

Expected user to be added to database, currently does not work.
